# Скрипт на shell

Tags: bash, unix, shell, freebsd

Написал небольшой скрипт(еще не дописан) на shell, но он некорректно работает. Вот код:

```
#!/bin/sh
#перейти на root
echo "Enter password for user root"
su root
if [ "$(id -u)" == "0" ]; then
    echo 'Вы вошли под пользователем root'
    #создание каталога /s и переход в него
    if [ -d /s ]; then
            echo 'Директория /s существует'
    else
            echo 'Отсутствие директории /s'
            mkdir s
            echo 'Create directory s'
    fi
    #создание каталога /proj
    echo 'Create directiry /proj'
    mkdir s/proj
    #передача прав на папку /s/proj пользователю
    user=""
    echo 'Enter your login: '
    read user
    echo "Передача папки пользователю"
    chown -R $user s/proj
    echo 'Выход из под пользователя root '
    exit
else
    echo 'Неверный пароль'
    exit 0
fi
```

Он не создает папку /proj и при входе под пользователем root не выводит 'Вы вошли под пользователем root'. Что не так с этим скриптом?

Comment: должно быть `"$(id -u)" -eq 0`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, ничего не изменилось, все так же при входе не выводит сообщение и не создается папка

Comment: опечатки: 1. третья и четвёртая строка — лишние. 2. вместо `/proj` дважды встречается `s/proj`

Comment: выполнив `su root` вы вышли из оболочки откуда был запущен скрипт и он прервался

Comment: первый s/proj для создания директории proj, а с командой chown мы передаем права доступа пользователю

Answer (score 1):

Самое главное:
Выполнив su root вы вышли из оболочки откуда был запущен скрипт и скрипт прервался

Ну и потом:

```
root_access_check ()
{
    if [[ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]] && grep -qv 'sudo' < <(id $UID); then
        echo 'For execute this script requires a root access.'
        eixt 1
    fi
}
```

1) `[[ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]]` Проверили не является пользователь root
2) `grep -qv 'sudo' < <(id $UID)` Проверили не состоит пользователь, от имени которого запущен скрипт, в sudo

> Если и то и другое нет, вышли из скрипта
>    Если все ок, то дальше все команды, кроме `read` и `echo` через `sudo`

```
if [ -d /s ]; then
            echo 'Директория /s существует'
    else
            echo 'Отсутствие директории /s'
            mkdir /s
            echo 'Create directory s'
fi
```

Меняем на `sudo mkdir -p /s` не так пафосно, зато практично ))

```
echo 'Enter your login: '
    read user
```

Смело меняем на `read -r -p 'Enter your login: ' user`

```
else
    echo 'Неверный пароль'
    exit 0
fi
```

> `exit 0` Означает что скрипт завешен без ошибок

`if [ "$(id -u)" == "0" ]; then`
ИМХО корректней так:
`if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then`
Но работать будет и так и так

**UPDATE**
Запускаем это `su -c './<script_name> "<путь_до_папки_где_хотите_создать_папку_юзеру>"'`

```
#!/bin/bash -e
declare user_name folder_name  parrent_missing parrent_folder_path user_group

parrent_folder_path="$1"
[[ "$parrent_folder_path" ]] || parrent_folder_path='.'

[[ -d "$parrent_folder_path" ]] || parrent_missing=1

while :
do
    clear
    read -r -p 'Enter the username for which the folder is created: ' user_name
    if grep -wq "$user_name" '/etc/passwd'; then
        user_group="$(id -gn "$user_name")"
        break
    else
        echo -e "\e[31mUser $user_name is not registered.\\nPlease check your entry   and try again.\e[m"
        sleep 5
    fi
done

read -r -p 'Enter the desired folder name: ' folder_name

mkdir -p "${parrent_folder_path}/${folder_name}" && echo -e "\e[32mFolder '${parrent_folder_path}/${folder_name}' was successfully created\e[m"

[[ "${parrent_missing}" ]] && echo -e "\e[33mFolder '$parrent_folder_path' was missing, but created\e[m"

chown "${user_name}:${user_group}" "${parrent_folder_path}/${folder_name}"
exit 0
```

> Если не указать "<путь_до_папки_где_хотите_создать_папку_юзеру>" то создаст в текущей папке

Comment: Проверяем `/s`, а создаём `s`. Разница есть? Зачем ключ `-p` для `mkdir`? Не вижу тут создания дерева подкаталогов. Shell — трудный язык программирования. Я вообще не понимаю, зачем народ в него постоянно пытается?

Comment: man mkdir читаем до конца _-p, --parents Создает недостающие родительские каталоги для каждого указанного каталога. Права доступа к родительским каталогам устанавливаются в значение umask, логически сложенное с 'u+wx'. Аргументы, соответствующие существующим каталогам, игнорируются. (Таким образом, если каталог /a существует, то 'mkdir /a' выдаст ошибку, а 'mkdir -p /a' -- нет.)_

Comment: Читайте мой комментарий до конца. Хотя бы четвёртое предложение от начала. И да, я в курсе, что такое `-p` у `mkdir`.

Comment: прочитал _Не вижу тут создания дерева подкаталогов_ Не понял к чему. `mkdir -p s` выполнится без ошибок вне зависимости есть каталог s или нет. Если нет создаст если нет пройдет мимо. Что и требовалоась

Comment: Да всё к тому же, к ненужности ключа `-p` в данном конкретном случае.

Comment: Ключь `-p` в данном случае дает отсутсвие ошибки если каталог s существует

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80897/discussion-between-andrey-karpov-and-0andriy).

Comment: На freebsd sudo не работает

Comment: Как сделать это все без команды sudo?

Comment: `su root -c './script-name'` и да, если память не изменяет, на freebsd, sudo работает, его просто устанвить нужно.

Comment: к сожалению, при установке были ошибки

Comment: @AndreyKarpov, su root -c './script-name' ошибка: './script-name' команда не найдена

Comment: Там должно быть название Вашего скрипта вместо script-name. И этой командой нужно скрипт запускать убрав из него проверку root. А вообще чтобы потренироваться в bash, поставьте лучше ubuntu, она подружелюбней, для этого дела

Comment: @AndreyKarpov, я писал имя своего скрипта и получил эту ошибку

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80914/discussion-between-zhuk-and-andrey-karpov).